# Bug in a dynamic menu written in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, menu

Everything runs ok if you do the actions slowly (opening/closing answers), but if you start clicking fast on a question everything is messed up!
It's the first time I try to write something with jQuery...Could you help me to find out what I did wrong?
Here is the working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cp4Jd/3/

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$('.expand').each(function(){
   var reducedHeight = $(this).height();
   $(this).css('height', 'auto');
   var fullHeight = $(this).height();
   $(this).height(reducedHeight);                
   $(this).data('reducedHeight', reducedHeight);
   $(this).data('fullHeight', fullHeight);
}).click(function() {
   $(this).animate({height: $(this).height() == $(this).data('reducedHeight') ? $(this).data('fullHeight') : $(this).data('reducedHeight')}, 500);
   $('.container').animate({height: $(this).height() == $(this).data('reducedHeight') ? 
        ($('.container').height() + $(this).data('fullHeight') - $(this).data('reducedHeight')) : 
        ($('.container').height() - $(this).data('fullHeight') + $(this).data('reducedHeight'))}, 500);                
   ($(this).height() == $(this).data('reducedHeight')) ? 
        ($(this).find('.menu_ico').attr('src', 'img/menu_minus.png')) : 
        ($(this).find('.menu_ico').attr('src', 'img/menu_plus.png'));
   }
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: A good practice is to `stop()` an animation before you start one, that way you clear the queue and you don't have that repetition. more info here http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I'd write an answer, but I'm going home soon! I will just say though, you're overcomplicating this a lot.. You could try have a look at the jQuery `.stop()` method too.

Comment: I thought that I was making this in a bad way, now you confirmed it! I'll take a look to the stop() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much simpler version for clarity.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="expand">
        <h2>This is a question?</h2>
        <p class="par_menu_content blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        <h2>Would you like to know the answer?</h2>            
        <p class="par_menu_content blue">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
            in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
            sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".par_menu_content").hide();

$(".expand h2").click(function(){
    var $h2 = $(this);
    $(".par_menu_content").slideUp();
    $h2.next().stop(true).animate({height:"toggle"},500);

});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 26px;
    -moz-border-radius: 26px;
    border-radius: 26px;
}
.expand {
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    padding: 2px;
    clear: both;
    float:left;
}
.par_menu_content {
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.blue {
    color:#008597;
}
```

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cp4Jd/9/)

Comment: This is ok, but how can I expand container too without having the problem I show?

Comment: You have to clear your container. I've updated my previous fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cp4Jd/10/

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot put a `<p>` inside another `<p>`.**

I always do this kind of accordions like this:

```
<outer wrapper>
    <item>
        <item content wrapper>
            <content>
        </item content wrapper>
    </item>

    <item>
        <item content wrapper>
            <content>
        </item content wrapper>
    </item>

    <item>
        <item content wrapper>
            <content>
        </item content wrapper>
    </item>
</outer wrapper>
```

you then give the `<item>` a fix height and animate the items' height to it's `<item content wrapper>`'s height and back its original, recuded height on second click (havent tested):

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
    if ($(this).height() == $(this).data('reducedHeight')) {
        $(this).stop().animate({height: $(this).children().height() + 50 + 'px'}, slow);
    }
    else {
        $(this).stop().animate({height: $(this).data('reducedHeight') + 'px'}, slow);
    }
});
```